# Should I re-seat my laptop wifi card to get it to work?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, wifi-driver

I'm running Windows 10 on Asus x412fa a mid range laptop.

Wifi shows turned off, without any way to turn it on again. I can turn it on from wifi under network and internet but nothing changes, available networks are not even shown and the turn Wi-Fi back on drop down is still there.

Window network diagnostics tells me to turn on wireless capability using the switch on my laptop or keyboard, but my laptop doesn't have one.

The option is also missing from 
Windows mobility center.

I have tried restarting, uninstalling drivers, disabling  the option that allows the computer to turn off device to save power.

Few days ago my fan was rattling so I opened up my laptop and cleaned it. Everything was good till 2 days later this happened. Should I reseat my wifi could that be a solution?

[Screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYDBv.jpg)
[Screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPXaV.jpg)

Comment: Since you opened the laptop and cleaned the interior, then by all means, you should remove the Wireless card, make sure it is clean and re-seat it. Then see if Device Manager sees it.

Comment: Thanks John, works now, but I'm gonna be in constant fear of having to do this again.

Comment: If I post an answer, will you acknowledge it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You opened the laptop and cleaned the interior. This disturbs dust inside the laptop.

So then by all means, you should remove the Wireless card, make sure it is clean and re-seat it. Then see if Device Manager sees it.

This will normally work .